# Add to Bloglines from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, rss

Is there an easy way to add an RSS feed in Chrome to your [Bloglines](http://www.bloglines.com/) account?

There are add-ons for IE and Firefox that let you do this.  Haven't seen anything for Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RSS Subscription Extension (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd)